# Não repetir dados ao fazer um SELECT no MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-select

O que eu quero é o seguinte. Estou trabalhando em um sistema, que cadastro um funcionário e dias em que ele trabalhou no mês. Até ai tudo bem, mas ocorre que em alguns casos, o funcionário fica com 2 ou mais registros no mesmo mês, por exemplo, cadastrei, entre os dias 21 e 25 de maio, e 28 e 30 de maio. Logo na minha tabela tem os seguinte registros:

```
1 - Funcionario1 - 5 (dias) - 5 (mês de maio)
2 - Funcionario1 - 3 (dias) - 5 (mês de maio)
```

Beleza, agora o que eu preciso é calcular o total de dias no meio de maio que esse funcionário trabalhou. Consigo mais ou menos com esse código:

```
for($i=0; $i<$mesatual; $i++) {
            echo "<h2>Plantões / ".$meses[$i]."</h2><br><br>";

            $query = "SELECT diasplantao.*, funcionarios.nome, funcionarios.atribuicao FROM diasplantao "
                    . "INNER JOIN funcionarios ON (diasplantao.funcionario_id = funcionarios.funcionario_id) WHERE (diasplantao.mes = $i+1) "
                    . "ORDER BY funcionarios.atribuicao DESC";

            $resultado = mysql_query($query);

            while($mostrar=mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                echo "<b>Nome:</b> ".$mostrar['nome']." -- ";
                echo "<b>Atribuição:</b> ".$mostrar['atribuicao']." -- ";
                echo "<b>Mês:</b> ".$mostrar['mes']." -- ";
                echo "<b>Dias:</b> ".$mostrar['dias']."<br><br>";

            }
        }  
    ?>
```

O código exibe o mês, e logo abaixo os dias que os funcionários trabalharam naquele mês.
Só que ele me retorna isso, no mês de março por exemplo.

```
Nome: George Cruijff Sales da Costa -- Atribuição: Analista -- Mês: 3 -- Dias: 12

Nome: George Cruijff Sales da Costa -- Atribuição: Analista -- Mês: 3 -- Dias: 10
```

Como faço para que não repita o nome, e qual a melhor forma de calcular o total dos dias? Eu estava pensando em colocar apenas uma variável auxiliar e somar, mas o nome vai continuar repetindo.

Alguém dá uma luz da melhor forma de se fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou dar um *group by* no `funcionarios.nome`?

Comment: Usei o GROUPY BY e consegui, mas agora como faço para fazer a soma, não sei se meu código ficou confuso, mas não to conseguindo fazer a soma.

Comment: E se tiver dois 'João da Silva' trabalhando na empresa?

Comment: Não preciso me preocupar com isso porque sei que não vai acontecer. Mas por precaução agrupei pelo id do funcionário. O problema mesmo agora é só a soma. Não posso errar nessa soma de jeito nenhum.

Comment: Cuidado que pode acontecer sim (nunca se sabe). Mas o ideal é agrupar por alguma propriedade que seja única (o id serve).

Comment: Agrupei por id já. Valeu =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o `SUM` para somar os dias e o `GROUP` para trazer as linhas agrupadas

```
SELECT diasplantao.mes, 
       SUM(diasplantao.dias) as dias,
       funcionarios.id,
       funcionarios.nome, 
       funcionarios.atribuicao 
FROM 
    diasplantao 
    INNER JOIN funcionarios ON (diasplantao.funcionario_id = funcionarios.funcionario_id) 
WHERE 
    (diasplantao.mes = $i+1)
GROUP BY
    funcionarios.id, diasplantao.mes, funcionarios.nome, funcionarios.atribuicao 
ORDER BY 
    funcionarios.atribuicao DESC
```

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado. Só uma ultima dúvida, porque usar o groupby para mes, nome, e atribuição também? Só o id não bastaria? Obrigado!

Comment: O Firebird costumava reclamar de `campo X não é agregatte e não está presente na cláusula GROUP BY` a partir daí eu criei a prática de agrupar todos os campos não calculados. Não sei se o MySQL não reclamaria, mas para ter uma SQL padrão eu acabei adotando este hábito. Então, se o MySQL não reclamar, acredito que não há problema

Comment: Entendi, valeu! Obrigadão.